# using createCriteria with order based on a belongsTo property

Tags: grails, belongs-to, createcriteria

I have the next scheme:

```
class UserProfile {
    String title
    String firstName
    String lastName 
    static belongsTo = [user:User]
    static constraints = {
            user nullable:true , unique:true
            title nullable:true, blank:true
            firstName blank:false
            lastName nullable:true, blank:true
    }
}

class User {
    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled 
    String email    
    static constraints = {
        username size:6..40, blank:false, nullable: false, unique: true
        email email:true, size:6..40, blank:false, nullable: false, unique: true
        password size:5..64, password:true, blank:false, nullable: false
    }   
    String toString(){username}
}
```

I need a list of `UserProfile` ordered by the email that has the user!

I try:

```
UserProfile.createCriteria().listDistinct({
    if(params.orderBy){
        if(params.orderBy=="email"){
        //the exception says that the element has no such property to both cases    
            order("user.email", ascDesc)
            //order("email", ascDesc)               
        }else{
            order("${params.orderBy}", ascDesc)
        }
    }

})
```

so when I want to order by the email the exception says that the element has no such property to both cases. Note: `ascDesc` is a variable `String` it can be `asc` or `desc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add

```
createAlias('user', 'u')
```

to the top of your criteria closure then you should be able to order by `'u.email'`.

Comment: excellent answer Ian, only it was only necessary to add this library: `import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification`

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to add any imports. Your IDE may complain that it doesn't recognise the createAlias method but that's the price you pay for dynamic DSLs - grails will accept it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (params.orderBy == "email") { 
    user { 
        order ("email", ascDesc) 
    } 
}
```

should work too without manual alias creation